# Compare two objects ASC and DESC by 2 fields using Comparable

Tags: java, sorting

I want to compare two objects of a class that implements Comparable, I need to compare the objects using two java.sql.Time Objects ASC and DESC, I sort them in mysql like this:

```
...order by startTime ASC, endTime DESC
```

and I need to sort them in java in the same way, but im using just:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Cita o) {
    return (getHoraInicio().compareTo(o.getHoraInicio()));
}
```

but I dont know how to sort them with two fields like mysql, ASC and DESC.
this is the full implementation of the class I want to sort.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.sql.Time;

public class Cita implements Comparable<Cita> {

public Time horaInicio;
public Time horaTermino;
public Paciente paciente;
public String actividad;
public String observacion;
public String recordar;
public String ciudad;
public String TipoCita;
public String fecha;
public int idPaciente;
public int idCita;

public Cita() {
}

public Cita(String fecha, Time horaInicio, Time horaTermino, int idPaciente, String actividad,
        String observacion, String recordar, String ciudad, String tipoCita) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
    this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
    this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
    this.actividad = actividad;
    this.observacion = observacion;
    this.recordar = recordar;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.TipoCita = tipoCita;
}

public Cita(int idCita, String fecha, Time horaInicio, Time horaTermino, Paciente paciente, String actividad,
        String observacion, String recordar, String ciudad, String tipoCita) {
    this.idCita = idCita;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
    this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
    this.paciente = paciente;
    this.actividad = actividad;
    this.observacion = observacion;
    this.recordar = recordar;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.TipoCita = tipoCita;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Cita o) {
    return (getHoraInicio().compareTo(o.getHoraInicio()));
}

public int getIdCita() {
    return idCita;
}

public void setIdCita(int idCita) {
    this.idCita = idCita;
}

public Time getHoraInicio() {
    return horaInicio;
}

public void setHoraInicio(Time horaInicio) {
    this.horaInicio = horaInicio;
}

public Time getHoraTermino() {
    return horaTermino;
}

public void setHoraTermino(Time horaTermino) {
    this.horaTermino = horaTermino;
}

public Paciente getPaciente() {
    return paciente;
}

public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
    this.paciente = paciente;
}

public String getActividad() {
    return actividad;
}

public void setActividad(String actividad) {
    this.actividad = actividad;
}

public String getObservacion() {
    return observacion;
}

public void setObservacion(String observacion) {
    this.observacion = observacion;
}

public String getRecordar() {
    return recordar;
}

public void setRecordar(String recordar) {
    this.recordar = recordar;
}

public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public String getTipoCita() {
    return TipoCita;
}

public void setTipoCita(String TipoCita) {
    this.TipoCita = TipoCita;
}

public int getIdPaciente() {
    return idPaciente;
}

public void setIdPaciente(int idPaciente) {
    this.idPaciente = idPaciente;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.idCita;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Cita other = (Cita) obj;
    if (this.idCita != other.idCita) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatohora = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
    return formatohora.format(horaInicio) + " - " + formatohora.format(horaTermino) + ", " + paciente.getNombre();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On tie do the compare using the "other" object as a your left-hand-side operand (effectively reversing the order). You could also do a normal compare on end times and negate the answer.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Cita o) {
    int asc = getHoraInicio().compareTo(o.getHoraInicio());
    if (asc != 0) { return asc; }
    return o.getHoraTermino.compareTo(getHoraTermino())
}
```

Note, I am assuming HoraTermino maps to `endTime`.